# REST service URI design

Tags: .net, rest

I am creating a RESTful service which needs to return a collection of items, but also needs to allow for filtering by several indexes (location, Company, and category).  These filters can be applied individually or in any combination.  Is this a situation where using filters applied in a query string make sense? (some something like: `/items?company={}&location={}&category={}`)  Is there a better way to pass filters to a resource?

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to pass search parameters is to use the query string (indeed, that's why it's called the query string). The path identifies the particular resource you want (an index of items). The query string may include, e.g., filter conditions, which are used to alter how the resource is represented - but it is still the same resource (an index of items), so the path should be the same.

Comment: Yes, with a nit. The truth is that the query parameters are themselves part of the identifier, and that different parameter values identify different resources. That is, `/thing?a=1` and `/thing?a=2` are distinct resources, not the same one. See http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-devel/msg/0fcc62df334bc9ed for more details.

Comment: At the level of HTTP and REST, the case can certainly be made that the query string is part of the resource identifier. In fact, this assumption is made in every application out there honoring URIs of the form `/page.aspx?id=345`. The `id` is, in this case, absolutely part of the resource identifier.

Comment: But at a higher level of abstraction, the application does not *have* to treat the query string as part of the resource identifier per se. Indeed, we should be designing our applications such that the resource identifier is entirely ensconced within the path. In some cases, we may include optional parameters in the query string, and the application in such cases should filter/sorts/limit or otherwise transform the representation of the resource based on the supplied parameters. If this rises above Roy Fielding's guiding principles for REST, it is nevertheless a simpler system.

Comment: And if, on a case-by-case basis, there is a reason we cannot honor this type of a system in an application we are working on, then we can drop down to permitting the query string to be part of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

This is the preferred way in a REST environment.  You *could* POST variables with the filter, but that would violate REST principals (in that the address should represent the resource).

Have you considered using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106)?  It does a great deal of this for you out-of-the-box in a standards-compliant way.

Answer (score 0):

In your route table you could do something like this:

```
"items/company/{organizationId?}/{locationId?}/{category?}"
```

and have your controller action look like this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Get(string organizationId, string locationId, string category) {
...
}
```

In my opinion, this beats querystrings as it is much more discoverable.

Comment: I must not understand what you mean by "discoverable". I would assume it means "the client can discover resources at runtime". But the hypertext constraint of REST demands that clients follow links the server gives them. It's quite easy to fill querystrings from HTML forms and provide lots of guidance along the way. How does one announce the scheme you gave above to a client at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

One simple rule will cover most if not all good practices;

```
If your filter parameters are optional then they should go to query string, 
if some filters are mandatory you may wanna put them into path. 
Adding optional params to path is not a good idea.
```